# Using UI-Router to make views change separately

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

It's possible to set the `ui-router` to change one view without changing any other?

For example: when navigating on the app, some actions are pointed to one `view`: the `view A`. However, the user can click on one link that is pointed to other `view` in the application: the `view B`. What I need is change the `view B` letting the `view A` on the same state that the user choosed before clicking on the link that changes the `view B`.

Someone please can help me with this one?

**EDIT:**

Here's the Plunkr with a close behavior: http://plnkr.co/edit/wJXx9R

Comment: _Please_ guys, I really need help with it.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) shows how to have a state configuration target specific views on the page.

Loading content into views independently of state navigation is not currently part of the API, but will be in an upcoming version.

Comment: Wow, that link went unnoticed when I looked in the documentation.

Comment: Well, I could not do what I need yet. I have 3 `views` in my application that need to be worked independently. Using the absolute way `(with the "@" character)`, with the `abstract: true`, when I browse in a view, the state of the other changes. I have to make them work independently.

Comment: Okay, maybe if you posted an example reproduction of your code in a Plunkr, I could help you figure out what to do.